# Constructor with one default argument

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm doing and exercise from a C++ book and I have this constructor prototype:

```
Person(const string & ln; const char * fn = "Heyyou");
```

Now I have to use this constructor this way:

```
Person two("Smythecraft");
```

So I should have the lname (data from the first parameter) set to "Smythecraft", and the fname (data from the second parameter) set to "Heyyou".

But this should also work with the same constructor:

Person three("Dimwiddy", "Sam");

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
Person::Person(const std::string &ln, const char * fn = "Heyyou")
{
    lname = ln;
    fname = fn;
}
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry? What's the problem? Other than a wrong character, your code seems to do what you want…

Comment: Cannot see any problem? If there is one tell us about it

Comment: "I tried this, but it doesn't work". What went wrong? Did you get an error? Post it. We can't help if we have no idea what you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

In your header:

```
class Person
{
public:
    // Declaration
    Person(const std::string &ln, const char * fn = "Heyyou");

    //...
};
```

And in your source file:

```
// Definition
Person::Person(const std::string &ln, const char * fn):
    lname( ln ),      // Prefer member-initialization-list
    fname( fn )
{
}
```

**You are not allowed to specify the default argument in the method definition when it is already done in the declaration.**

Also, you should prefer to use *member-initialization-list* when it is possible. The first post of [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17820/) quotes *Scott Meyers* about the advantage of using *member-initialization-list*.

Comment: You not only don't need to specify the default argument, but you're not allowed to. It can only be specified once.

Comment: @PeteBecker Bad wording... I changed that ! Thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess at your problem, because you mentioned a constructor prototype.

You can't specify default arguments in both the prototype *and* the implementation. Just specify them in the prototype and leave the implementation like a normal function. Like this:

```
// in class
Person(const string & ln, const char * fn = "Heyyou");

// later
Person::Person(const std::string &ln, const char * fn) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need default parameter value specified in method implementation that is separate from its declaration since it has been already specified in `Person(const string & ln; const char * fn = "Heyyou");` inside your class. This:

```
Person::Person(const std::string &ln, const char * fn)
{
    lname = ln;
    fname = fn;
}
```

should work.